# Craft CMS 3 - Internal Server Error on certain pages

Tags: http-status-code-500, craftcms

After upgrading to Craft 3 from 2, I'm getting a 500 Internal Server Error on a select few pages.  For example:

- /reports (Doesn't work)
- /reports/slug (Works)
- /publications (Doesn't work)
- /publications/slug (Works)

For some reason it's not the same for all paths.  `/media` works just fine.  This is what shows up in my logs but I have no idea what it means.  Also, the error screen I get is a Craft-styled page.

```
2020-09-25 00:37:46 [-][1][80b3e94259710a336582ea71cac98d1a][info][application] $_GET = [
    'p' => 'publications'
]

$_POST = []

$_FILES = []

$_COOKIE = [
    'CraftSessionId' => '80b3e94259710a336582ea71cac98d1a'
    '1031b8c41dfff97a311a7ac99863bdc5_identity' => 'f108309014ae583a6eb6ce545f6acdd1c25222a18bee9c382e0050742d3cd949a:2:{i:0;s:41:\"1031b8c41dfff97a311a7ac99863bdc5_identity\";i:1;s:246:\"[\"1\",\"[\\\"xS6JjF6hHAbX59SK5XGpi5Ktmw-FTf-phJhV7uix7aalULuGzl308wNhAVNTGY2dPm7xXOk6dLOgaR2NbBXEqhhZFF649LoNhLnu\\\",null,\\\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36\\\"]\",1209600]\";}'
    '1031b8c41dfff97a311a7ac99863bdc5_username' => '9a33d470ce6b2e033bab618b31164d34798869ae07d8c7515cc445de0603e560a:2:{i:0;s:41:\"1031b8c41dfff97a311a7ac99863bdc5_username\";i:1;s:25:\"mollie@email.com\";}'
    'CRAFT_CSRF_TOKEN' => '•••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••'
]

$_SESSION = [
    'bd62416aa8538ede709019a5e113eea5__flash' => []
    '1031b8c41dfff97a311a7ac99863bdc5__token' => '••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••'
    '1031b8c41dfff97a311a7ac99863bdc5__id' => '1'
    '1031b8c41dfff97a311a7ac99863bdc5__expire' => 1600997866
    'bd62416aa8538ede709019a5e113eea5__auth_access' => [
        0 => 'editStructure:5'
        1 => 'editStructure:11'
        2 => 'editStructure:9'
        3 => 'editStructure:6'
        4 => 'editStructure:8'
    ]
]

$_SERVER = [
    'TMP' => '/srv/users/serverpilot/tmp/water-institute'
    'TEMP' => '/srv/users/serverpilot/tmp/water-institute'
    'TMPDIR' => '/srv/users/serverpilot/tmp/water-institute'
    'PATH' => '/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'
    'USER' => 'serverpilot'
    'HOME' => '/srv/users/serverpilot'
    'SCRIPT_NAME' => '/index.php'
    'REQUEST_URI' => '/publications'
    'QUERY_STRING' => 'p=publications'
    'REQUEST_METHOD' => 'GET'
    'SERVER_PROTOCOL' => 'HTTP/1.0'
    'GATEWAY_INTERFACE' => 'CGI/1.1'
    'REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING' => 'p=publications'
    'REDIRECT_URL' => '/publications'
    'REMOTE_PORT' => '38390'
    'SCRIPT_FILENAME' => '/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/water-institute/public/index.php'
    'SERVER_ADMIN' => 'webmaster@'
    'CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT' => '/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/water-institute/public'
    'CONTEXT_PREFIX' => ''
    'REQUEST_SCHEME' => 'https'
    'DOCUMENT_ROOT' => '/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/water-institute/public'
    'REMOTE_ADDR' => '209.555.242.105'
    'SERVER_PORT' => '443'
    'SERVER_ADDR' => '127.0.0.1'
    'SERVER_NAME' => 'dev.thewaterinstitute.org'
    'SERVER_SOFTWARE' => 'Apache/2.4.46 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2g'
    'SERVER_SIGNATURE' => ''
    'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' => '/opt/sp/apache/lib:/opt/sp/apache/lib'
    'HTTP_COOKIE' => 'CraftSessionId=80b3e94259710a336582ea71cac98d1a; 1031b8c41dfff97a311a7ac99863bdc5_identity=f108309014ae583a6eb6ce545f6acdd1c25222a18bee9c382e0050742d3cd949a%3A2%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A41%3A%221031b8c41dfff97a311a7ac99863bdc5_identity%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A246%3A%22%5B%221%22%2C%22%5B%5C%22xS6JjF6hHAbX59SK5XGpi5Ktmw-FTf-phJhV7uix7aalULuGzl308wNhAVNTGY2dPm7xXOk6dLOgaR2NbBXEqhhZFF649LoNhLnu%5C%22%2Cnull%2C%5C%22Mozilla%2F5.0+%28Windows+NT+10.0%3B+Win64%3B+x64%29+AppleWebKit%2F537.36+%28KHTML%2C+like+Gecko%29+Chrome%2F85.0.4183.83+Safari%2F537.36%5C%22%5D%22%2C1209600%5D%22%3B%7D; 1031b8c41dfff97a311a7ac99863bdc5_username=9a33d470ce6b2e033bab618b31164d34798869ae07d8c7515cc445de0603e560a%3A2%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A41%3A%221031b8c41dfff97a311a7ac99863bdc5_username%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A25%3A%22mollie%40email.com%22%3B%7D; CRAFT_CSRF_TOKEN=25773457aeb176b611944eb8242d07ca89d6db0513942ffa87741e60f6789b13a%3A2%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A16%3A%22CRAFT_CSRF_TOKEN%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A208%3A%226WM7NPL9Vbakyko4DJ-9pHHorwTsXXoGGZTOowAj%7Cedd0c62c7d374da3e339e8d4cc1fa8143778f59331f0d207580bec8e76567a666WM7NPL9Vbakyko4DJ-9pHHorwTsXXoGGZTOowAj%7C1%7C%242y%2413%24SPzKwYvJwBZgGjgrnHip6u2WVgGOtTJhn4Rix9UqItYl1o%2FMzgRZK%22%3B%7D'
    'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE' => 'en-US,en;q=0.9,la;q=0.8'
    'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING' => 'gzip, deflate, br'
    'HTTP_SEC_FETCH_DEST' => 'document'
    'HTTP_SEC_FETCH_USER' => '?1'
    'HTTP_SEC_FETCH_MODE' => 'navigate'
    'HTTP_SEC_FETCH_SITE' => 'none'
    'HTTP_ACCEPT' => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9'
    'HTTP_USER_AGENT' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36'
    'HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS' => '1'
    'HTTP_CONNECTION' => 'close'
    'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO' => 'https'
    'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SSL' => 'on'
    'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR' => '209.555.242.105'
    'HTTP_HOST' => 'dev.mydomain.org'
    'SCRIPT_URI' => 'https://dev.mydomain.org/publications'
    'SCRIPT_URL' => '/publications'
    'HTTPS' => 'on'
    'REDIRECT_STATUS' => '200'
    'REDIRECT_SCRIPT_URI' => 'https://dev.mydomain.org/publications'
    'REDIRECT_SCRIPT_URL' => '/publications'
    'REDIRECT_HTTPS' => 'on'
    'FCGI_ROLE' => 'RESPONDER'
    'PHP_SELF' => '/index.php'
    'REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT' => 1600994266.1376
    'REQUEST_TIME' => 1600994266
    'argv' => [
        0 => 'p=publications'
    ]
    'argc' => 1
    'ENVIRONMENT' => 'dev'
    'SECURITY_KEY' => '••••••••••••••••'
    'DB_DRIVER' => 'mysql'
    'DB_SERVER' => 'localhost'
    'DB_USER' => 'e39b766ddf0a'
    'DB_PASSWORD' => '••••••••••••••••'
    'DB_DATABASE' => 'water-institute'
    'DB_SCHEMA' => 'public'
    'DB_TABLE_PREFIX' => 'craft'
    'DB_PORT' => ''
    'ROOT_URL' => 'https://dev.mydomain.org'
]
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having a similar issue and it's driving me insane.